# Can't get axis labels to show on r plot()

Tags: r, plot

I'm working with the meuse dataset in the sp library in R and I'm just trying to obtain a simple plot of the meuse grid which highlights the different areas of flooding frequency. However, I can't seem to get the axis labels to display. I've tried using a par() statement beforehand but it doesn't appear to be doing anything?

```
data(meuse.grid) #in sp library
summary(meuse.grid)
str(meuse.grid)
coordinates(meuse.grid) = ~x+y
proj4string(meuse.grid)<-CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
gridded(meuse.grid)=TRUE
class(meuse.grid)
par(mar=c(10,10,4,2)+0.1,mgp=c(5,1,0))
plot(meuse.grid["ffreq"], scale.frac = 0.6,main="Flooding Frequency Class Map", 
xlab="Easting",ylab="Northing",axes=TRUE)
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you put an image of your plot in please - I ran your code and had no problems

Comment: @rg255 Just added it there - it looks that way if I save the plot as a pdf as well.

Comment: Now I see it, easting and northing are missing - if you set `plot(...line = 0)` you'll see it is plotting them, it appears that they are outside the margins which is odd...

Comment: Seems like a bug of `sp` class plotting method to me. See workaround provided in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `mtext` as a fix, expand slightly outer margins `oma` in advance. You could also fix the title with this method.

```
par(mar=c(10,10,4,2) + 0.1, mgp=c(5,1,0), oma=c(2, 2, 2, 2))
plot(meuse.grid["ffreq"], scale.frac = 0.6,main="", 
     xlab="",ylab="",axes=TRUE)
mtext("Easting", side=1, line=3, font=2)
mtext("Northing", side=2, line=3, font=2)
mtext("Flooding Frequency Class Map", side=3, line=1, font=2, cex=1.2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the plot margins by setting `par()` before your `plot()` function. The default values are:

```
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)
```

where each number represents a side of the plot (bottom, left, top, right). setting the outer margins via `par(oma)` (in a similar way to above) might also help.